# iPhone: Crashing when sorting based on number

Tags: iphone

I have an NSArray output. please refer below. I want to sort based on particular number field (Order) in it. Please refer the code below.

```
Log: resultArray:
(
        {
        Name = "Myname1";
        Id = "dummyID";
        Order = 0; 
        parexId = 15;
        "__type" = "Question:#myAPI";
    },
        {
        Name = "Myname2";
        Id = "fatID";
        Order = 1; 
        parexId = 16;
        "__type" = "Question:#myAPI";
    }
        {
        Name = "Myname3";
        Id = "colorID";
        Order = 2; 
        parexId = 17;
        "__type" = "Question:#myAPI";
    }

)
```

Code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Order" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { 
            return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; 
    }];
    resultArray = [resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]]; // resultArray contents the above output values.
```

BUT it is crashing when compare happens during sorting.
Crash error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber compare:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b514b0
```

Could someone please help me, what i'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is a number field. It does not have method compare:options. You should use

[obj1 compare:obj2];

Answer (score 0):

Use like below it will work fine

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Order" ascending:YES];
    [resultArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
    [aSortDescriptor release];
```

Comment: It gives compilation error as "Receiver type NSArray for instance message does not declare a method with selector arrayWithObject"

Comment: resultArray should be NSMutableArray